# ggraph arc diagram clips label text

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph, ggraph, arc-diagram

I am using the `igraph` and `ggraph` package to plot an arc diagram. I am having trouble with the `geom_node_text` parameter because, as the length of the text label increases, the graph lower margin will not increase accordingly. So if the label for a node is a bit long, it ends up getting clipped off from the plot.

Here is a reproducible example using the `karate` sample data from the `igraphdata` package.

```
data(karate)
ggraph(karate, layout="linear")+
  geom_edge_arc(aes(edge_width=weight), edge_alpha=0.5, fold=T)+
  geom_node_point(aes(size=strength(karate), color=as.factor(color)))+
  geom_node_text(aes(label=name), angle=90, hjust=1, nudge_y = -0.2, size=4)+
  theme_void()+theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

I have already tried to change the plot margins via the `theme(plot.margin=)` but the labels get clipped off anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` in your plot and expand the plot margins:

```
data(karate)

ggraph(karate, layout = "linear") +
  geom_edge_arc(aes(edge_width = weight), edge_alpha = 0.5, fold = TRUE) +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = strength(karate), color = as.factor(color))) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), angle = 90, hjust = 1, nudge_y = -0.2, size = 4) +   
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") + 
  theme_void() +  
  theme(legend.position = "none", plot.margin = unit(rep(30, 4), "points"))
```

[image]